# How do remove a particular change number in perforce?

Tags: perforce

I have a perforce client which synced to a particular change number. I want to remove changes for a particular change number.

eg. lets say I have a function in a file.

```
void printnames() {      //M
    printf("John\n");      //M
    printf("Joseph\n");    //N
    printf("Harry\n");     //M
    printf("Mary\n");      //N
}
```

where M and N denote the latest change numbers which added/modified these lines. I want to remove change number N(or if I may say - unsync change number N).
Is it possible to do that, and what would be the steps? (I want to this for Perforce). I know I can manually p4 edit the file, but that's not what I am looking for.

Comment: http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/3474

Comment: Do you just want to get the previous version of the file sync'd to your workspace? If so, 'p4 sync @M' will synchronize your workspace back to change M (which is, as you say, before change N). Or is change N a mistake, and you wish you hadn't made that change? If so, submit a new change which undoes change N, as jamesdlin suggests in the above comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
p4 sync @(N-1)
p4 sync -k @(N)
p4 reconcile
```

And then optionally (if there are changes after N you want to sync to your workspace, which will be necessary if you want to submit the change that undoes N):

```
p4 sync
p4 resolve [-am]
```